# Some URLs not displayed in PHP/ PDF-Wordpress-Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, url, pdf, tcpdf

I am using POST2PDF (based on TCPDF) to create PDFs of my blog posts. But I am running into an issue that the plugin won't display some URLs in the posts.

This URL is displayed in the PDF:

> http://www.aestheticsandculture.net/index.php/jac/article/view/5677/6304

This URL is not displayed in the PDF:

> http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2014-11-27-this-war-of-mine-made-its-money-back-in-just-two-days

Can somebody tell me why? What might be a possible solution?

Comment: I messed around a bit with my links and found out that they are displayed in the Pdf if they are not longer than 91 characters.